# Inactive thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading

In applications where I use threads I usually create them, I start them and wait for them to end up using the join method.
I observe that there is a time when the main process is inactive and I do not know the reason. In the attached graphic it can be verified that there are four threads working and the main thread presents a time of inactivity. It's represented in violet in the next graphic:

[image]

Why does that downtime appear? Thank you

Comment: What does "inactive" mean? Could you provide legenda for your chart for understanding what different colours mean?

Comment: Green means that the thread is running. Violet means that the thread is inactive and yellow means that the thread is waiting.

Comment: But what does 'inactive' mean? In Oracle Java Mission Control violet means, that thread sleeps. And there is no term 'inactive'. What tool do you use for threads analyzis?

Comment: Inactive or sleeping, I don't care. The main thread should be working until the four threads in the bottom start doing their job. I'm using the profile tool in Netbeans.

Comment: It could be important. Could you provide your code?

Comment: You can see the same behavior in all the codes. For example, in the next one, the thread of the main method sleeps and I don't know why:package threads;

class Hilo extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Hilo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}

public class Threads {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Hilo hilo = new Hilo();
        hilo.start();
        hilo.join();
    }
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158660/discussion-between-alberto-and-donz).

Comment: Please add code to the question, don't use comments for pertinent information. And given your main thread has called `hilo.join()`, of course it is waiting: it is waiting for hilo to finish. What did you expect?

Answer (score 2):

I edited and compiled your example and wrote JFR. In JMC I see the same as in any other multithreaded java application. So I think the problem is in profiler tool.
May be it stops main thread in unusual way for monitoring purposes. May be it is just wrong. Use Oracle Java Mission Control. This tool have to be right.

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to get the same graphic with Oracle Java Mission Control but I don't know how to do it. After open Netbeans and JMC, I start flight recorder and run the application. After that, I go to Events-Graph in JMC but inside main I only see something called AWT-EventQueue. Could you tell me the steps? Thank you very much.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jmc-5-4/jfr-runtime-guide/run.htm#JFRUH164 - here you can learn how to run JFR recorder. Try to do it from command line - it is really simplier than from any IDE with special arguments. In your case it should be something like that: `java -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:StartFlightRecording=duration=60s,filename=myrecording.jfr threads.Threads`
After that open jmc from %JDK_HOME%/bin and open this file. Go to Events-Graph and you'll see the screenshot above.